# Can connection being established before procedures hooked on startup event being executed in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to do some cleanups and custom initialization before the MySQL server can accept connections, Can connection being established before

```
init_file = '.../startup.sql';
```

is executed?

If not, is there any alternative methods to make it possible, like temporary global variables that reset every time the server starts?

Comment: Step back a moment: What are you trying to prevent/achieve? Clients from grabbing info while an sql server is starting up? Why aren't these values able to be saved into the DB directly or made via a temp table / view?

Comment: I'm making ORM and it should clean those reference records that are not removed if the database is shut accidentally so that the garbage collector can run properly. @Rogue

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable in the mysqld config file and have your tasks change that value after they complete. It would be reset every time the server starts. That would work as the flag you are looking for. You could also use an EVENT to check for that.

However, you would be better scripting the start up process of your MySQL service to carry out your cleanup tasks once it returned that it was up and establishing a connection locally to execute them. You could, if it's critical, have this same process enable remote connections only after it had executed its tasks.